# TypeError: jQuery(...).endlessScroll is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have image scrolling page in my php project, 
in this page i have an error type error.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery("#s1").endlessScroll({
        width: '10%',
        height: '100px',
        steps: -2,
        speed: 40,
        mousestop: true
    });
    jQuery("#s2").endlessScroll({
        width: '700px',
        height: '26px',
        steps: -2,
        speed: 40,
        mousestop: false
    });
});
```

i don't know how to solve this error, anyone guide me, to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you include the **endless-scroll** plugin right after the jquery is included in your page?

Comment: i included full-script  before of these lines

Comment: What does it mean **full-script**? Are you using the **endless-scroll** plugin? Or you are including just jQuery?

Comment: Could you post some example fiddle?

Comment: i am using endless-scroll script it has separate file , i am just include the file name to this page.

Comment: So is it correct that you have somewhere in the **body** element two *script* elements, first has *src* attribute set to the jquery file, and the second one has *src* attribute set to the jquery endless scroll file? and after these two script element, you have third script element with the code you supplied?

Comment: If you see the error **jQuery(…).endlessScroll is not a function**, it could be because you are not including the endlessScroll plugin (which said you did), or you are including it before including jquery, or you are calling your script before the includes, or somewhere in the page you are including jQuery again, and this include removes the endlessScroll plugin from the jQuery as it is reinitialized

Comment: ok i will try to include same page